GPU ID nomenclature in PyTorch and TensorFlow
How will docker assign GPUs to the containers?
Does GPU ID change when I have 3 docker containers running on a machine with 3 GPUs?

Docker itself doesn't natively manage the allocation of GPUs to containers. However, NVIDIA's runtime for Docker, known as NVIDIA Container Toolkit (formerly NVIDIA Docker), provides a mechanism to pass through GPUs to containers in a controlled fashion.
When you start a Docker container with NVIDIA Container Toolkit, you specify which GPUs to make available to the container using the --gpus flag. You can assign specific GPUs to each container, and the ID of the GPUs inside the container will correspond to the subset of GPUs you have assigned.
For example, if you have 3 GPUs on the host machine, and you want to run 3 different containers, each using a different GPU, you would start each container like this:
# Assign GPU 0 to container1
docker run --gpus '"device=0"' -d container1

# Assign GPU 1 to container2
docker run --gpus '"device=1"' -d container2

# Assign GPU 2 to container3
docker run --gpus '"device=2"' -d container3

Inside each container, the GPU assigned will appear as GPU 0 since it's the only one visible to that container. That means that from the perspective of any frameworks running inside the container (be it TensorFlow, PyTorch, etc.), they will only see one GPU and it will be indexed as 0.
This abstraction allows each container to work with the GPUs as if they are the only user of that GPU, without worrying about the actual GPU ID on the host system. This makes it simpler to develop and deploy applications since your code doesn't need to be aware of the host's GPU configuration.
If you want to make all GPUs available to a container but still restrict each application to use a specific one, you'd still use the --gpus flag, and inside the container, you would control which GPU to use using the specific framework's GPU selection method (like setting CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES environment variable).
Please note, to use the --gpus flag, you need to have the NVIDIA Container Toolkit installed on your host system and the Docker daemon needs to be configured to use the nvidia-container-runtime as its default runtime or specify it when running the container.
